# Upgrade WAMP to MySQL 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

My dev team uses WAMP for the php/Mysql environment but i just learnt that uses MySQL 5.1 and MySQL is at 5.5 now. Can I get the mysql upgraded to 5.5 separately without any issue to make it work with WAMP or is there any patch for WAMP to get the latest mysql?

I want to ensure they work with the latest build of MySQL but i am not sure if it is as simple as download mySQL 5.5 and it gets auto-added to the WAMP server, or if there are compatible? I assume since WAMP never updated their MySQL something is not compatible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Found this for you:

STEP1: (x represents a number)

> Download the latest version of MySQL
>   first... Copy the new folder of
>   mysqlx.x to wamp\bin\mysql\ Check if
>   the folder of mysql and all database
>   files exist in mysqlx.x\data folder.
>   If the mysql folder doesn't exist,
>   copy it from a working previous
>   version of mysql.
>
> Check if mysqlx.x\bin folder and all
>   executable files in it exist. Check if
>   the folder mysqlx.x\share exist. If
>   they don't exist, then the extraction
>   of the latest version of mysql isn't
>   done properly.
>
> Check if mysqlx.x\my.ini file exist.
>   If it doesn't exist, copy the file
>   from the previous wokring version of
>   wamp mysql in wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.x
>   Open the file from the latest mysql
>   version, edit all occurrences of
>   "mysqlx.x" in that file to the
>   "mysqlx.x" as the latest version
>   number.
>
> For example, if you see the line
>   "basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql4.1"
>   in my.ini file, then edit it to
>   "basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlx.x"
>   as mysqlx.x is the lastest version
>   you've just downloaded. Normally there
>   are only two occurrences you need to
>   edit:
>   basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlx.x and
>   datadir=c:'wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlx.x/data

STEP2:

> Copy the wampserver.conf file in the
>   previous version of wamp mysqlx.x
>   folder to wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.x. You
>   would need to open it with notepad and
>   edit the line:
>   $mysqlConf['mysqlExeFile'] =
>   'mysqld-nt.exe'; to
>   $mysqlConf['mysqlExeFile'] =
>   'mysqld.exe';
>
> Look at the mysqlx.x\bin directory and
>   find out if there is a mysqld.exe or
>   mysql-nt.exe file. If there is no
>   mysql-nt.exe file, then change that
>   line as mentioned.

STEP3:

> Shutdown the wamp2 server (by right
>   click on wamp tray icon and click
>   exit). Then restart the wamp server.
>   Restart all services. You should see
>   the mysql newest version displayed in
>   wamp mysql menu. Just click on the
>   latest version to enable it, then you
>   have the newest mysql version running
>   with wamp server.

Comment: I tried the instructions above, and it was still running the earlier version of MySQL. In addition to steps above, you need to also change the version number/folder in wampmanager.ini, wampmanager.conf, and use regedit to change the version in the registry for MySQL and the wampmysqld service

Comment: thanks for this it worked like a charm! and to the comment above WAMP does all that automatically, after step 3 close and open Wamp server and look for mysql newest version displayed in wamp mysql menu, select it and WAMP a automatically edits, wampmanager.ini and MySQL version in regedit! hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

After doing all mention above. There is few more step, how to enable new MySQL.

1. Start WAMP.
2. Left click on WAMP tray.
3. Click MySQL->Version->your new MySQL version(mine is MySQL 5.7.9).
4. Click MySQL->Service->Install service.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for their help. I am detailing certain steps I took from editing registry onwards:

While editing registry

1. Replaced all occurrences of `5.0.45`(my older version of mysql) pertaining to mysql with `5.5.28`(My new version of mysql)
2. Replaced all occurrences of `mysqld-nt.exe` pertaining to mysql with `mysqld.exe`

When I started the wamp, the system didn't recognize the my.ini entry 
`default-character-set=latin1` 
The reason was that the entry was in `[wampmysqld]` section. 
Then I created `[sql]` section and shifted the entry there.
I restarted wamp and MySQL started with new version.