# Program 'mysql.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd, wampserver

I have problem with `mysql` command in windows 10. I want to import a file `test.sql` to `test` database. I use this command in Windows PowerShell

```
.\mysql -u root -p test < test.sql
```

PS return an error with this content

```
Program 'mysql.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1
char:1
+ .\mysql -u root -p
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\mysql -u root -p
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I tried in windows CMD(also administrate) I get this message `This app can't run in your PC`

also I find `mysql.exe` in `c/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql5.7.11/bin`
  the size of the app was wierd `0KB`.

Is it normal?

what 's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed a new version of mysql using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498322/upgrade-wamp-to-mysql-5-5)
and it worked in new version of mysql

Answer (score 1):

Well - it is not normal, size of the app should be more than 0kb, depends on the version. My guess is mysql was not installed correctly. Maybe antivirus blocked it during installation?
Try to reinstall WAMP package. Also - when you start WAMP - do this with elevated privileges.
Is your windows 64 bit? Also - if reinstalling the package would not work despite antivirus switched off or even not present, try to download and install 32bit package.